# Как нарисовать график такого вида(nrz кодирование)?

Tags: python, matplotlib, график

Имеется список бит, введенный пользователем. Нужно по этим битам нарисовать график NRZ кодирования сигнала.

> NRZ (Non Return to Zero) (англ. без возвращения к нулю) — двухуровневый код, в соответствие с которым логическому нулю соответствует нижний уровень, логической единице — верхний уровень. Информационные переходы происходят на границе значащих интервалов (значащий момент).

Таким образом, на выходе должен получиться график такого вида(верхний):
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вопрос: как называется график такого вида и какую функцию библиотеки matplotlib нужно использовать, чтобы его отрисовать?

Comment: вы можете привести примеры данных?

Comment: чтобы выбрать подходящий метод - посмотрите в [галерее](https://matplotlib.org/gallery.html)...

Comment: график не соответствует описанию (перепутаны 0 и 1). Попробуйте [`plt.step()` функцию.](https://matplotlib.org/2.0.0/examples/pylab_examples/step_demo.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Да, нашел. [plt.step()](https://matplotlib.org/2.0.0/examples/pylab_examples/step_demo.html) именно то, что мне было нужно.

Comment: пример кода, который графика показывающий NRZ кодирование сигнала, мог бы улучшить ответ.